# Como varrer um vetor em PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um jogo de pergunta e resposta em php, ja esta funcionando a comparação, no entanto, estou com um problema, quando eu clico em responder o vetor vai para o ultimo indice, ou seja, ultima pergunta. tentei colocar um Rand, mas nesse caso ele faz a mesma coisa e repete a mesma pergunta. Sinto que eu não estou sabendo onde colocar o laço.

```
<?php 






$banco = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db_ingles");
$banco->set_charset('utf8');
if($banco->connect_errno != 0){
    echo "<h1> Erro de conexao no banco</h1>Erro: ". $banco->connect_errno . "</h2>";
}else{
    //conectado
}


$id = 0;
$pergunta= "";
$resposta= "";
$msg= "";
$erros = 0;



if (isset($_POST["btResponder"])) {

    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $pergunta = $_POST["pergunta"];
    $resposta = $_POST["respostacorreta"];





    if(strcasecmp($resposta, $_POST["resposta"]) == 0){
        $msg = "<h1> acertou : $resposta </h1>";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $retorno = mysqli_query($banco, $sql); 
    $registro = mysqli_fetch_array($retorno);



    $id = $registro["id"];
    $pergunta = $registro["pergunta"];
    $resposta = $registro["resposta"];

    }else{

        $msg = "<h1> Errada a resposta correta é: $resposta </h1> <br>";



    }

}else{
    // escolher uma pergunta

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $retorno = mysqli_query($banco, $sql);
    $registro = mysqli_fetch_array($retorno);
    $id = $registro["id"];
    $pergunta = $registro["pergunta"];
    $resposta = $registro["resposta"];



}





 ?>

<?php



 require_once '../config/header.inc.html'; ?>  <!-- Importando o cabeçalho la do arquivo header -->

<div class="row container">
    <div class="col s12">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>



         <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>


    <title>perguntas</title>
 </head>
 <body>


    <h3>Word: <?php echo $pergunta; ?></h3>

    <form method="post" action="#" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
    <input type="text" name="resposta" required autofocus/>
    <label for="search">Digite a resposta</label>
    </div>


    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="pergunta" value="<?php echo $pergunta; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="respostacorreta" value="<?php echo $resposta; ?>">

    <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
    <input type="submit" name="btResponder" value="Responder" class="btn"/><br><br>
    </div>
    </form>



    <?php echo $msg; ?>





    <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    });

</script>


 </body>
 </html>


    </div>

</div>




<?php require_once '../config/footer.inc.html' ?>  <!-- Importando o rodape la do arquivo footer -->























?>
```

Comment: Isso aqui `for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++) { $registro = mysqli_fetch_array($retorno); }` sempre retornará o último elemento em registro, pois estará pois um loop de sobrescrição do  último valor adicionado.  Não entendi o que quer fazer, mas se deseja obter uma array com todas as respostas poderia fazer `for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++) { $registro[] = mysqli_fetch_array($retorno); }`

Comment: Outra opção seri usar [`fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Comment: Eu quero simplesmente passar posição por posição cada vez que eu clico em responder. mas talves eu nao esteja sabendo onde colocar o for no local correto

Comment: Então você tem que colocar as operações que manipulam `$registro` dentro do `for`. O que fizer fora do `for` sempre será no último registro iterado.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá,

Veja agora se funciona!

Já corrigi para a verificação da resposta ser CASE-INSENSITIVE (tanto faz maiúscula ou minúscula)!

```
<?php 

/*
MEUS DADOS PARA TESTE

$perguntas = array(

    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'pergunta' => 'sapo',
        'resposta' => 'frog',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'pergunta' => 'vaca',
        'resposta' => 'cow',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'pergunta' => 'leão',
        'resposta' => 'lion',
    )

);

$rand = rand(0,2);
$registro = $perguntas[ $rand ];
*/

// CONECTA NO BANCO DE DADOS
$banco = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db_ingles");

// SE NÃO CONECTA NO BANCO, DIE
if(!$banco) die("<h1>Erro de conexao no banco</h1>Erro: ". $banco->connect_errno);

// SET CHARSET
$banco->set_charset('utf8');

// VARIAVEIS INICIAIS
$mostraMensagemResposta = false;

// RESPOSTA FORNECIDA
if ( isset($_POST["btResponder"]) ) {

    // STATUS DA RESPOSTA
    $isRespostaCorreta = false;

    // TERÁ QUE MOSTRAR UMA MENSAGEM RESPOSTA
    $mostraMensagemResposta = true;

    $postPergunta = $_POST["pergunta"];
    $postRespostaCorreta = $_POST["respostacorreta"];
    $postResposta = $_POST["resposta"];

    // VERIFICA SE A RESPOSTA ESTÁ CORRETA - CASE-INSENSITIVE
    if( strtolower($postRespostaCorreta) === strtolower($postResposta) ){

        $isRespostaCorreta = true;

    }

} // FIM RESPOSTA FORNECIDA

// escolher uma pergunta

$sql = "SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$retorno = mysqli_query($banco, $sql);
$registro = mysqli_fetch_array($retorno);

$id = $registro["id"];
$pergunta = $registro["pergunta"];
$resposta = $registro["resposta"];

?>
<?php 
/* CABEÇALHO */
require_once '../config/header.inc.html'; ?>

<?php 

// MOSTRA SE A RESPOSTA ESTÁ CORRETA OU ERRADA
if($mostraMensagemResposta === true){ 

?>
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col s12">
        <p>Word: <?php echo $postPergunta; ?><br>
        Sua reposta: <?php echo $postResposta; ?><br>
        <strong>ESTÁ <?php echo $isRespostaCorreta === true ? 'CORRETA' : 'ERRADA'; ?></strong>
        <?php if($isRespostaCorreta === false){ ?><br>Correto: <strong><?php echo $postRespostaCorreta ?></strong> <?php }?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } // FIM MOSTRAR RESPOSTA ?>
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col s12">
    <h3>Word: <?php echo $pergunta; ?></h3>
    <form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
    <input type="text" name="resposta" required autofocus/>
    <label for="search">Digite a resposta</label>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="pergunta" value="<?php echo $pergunta; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="respostacorreta" value="<?php echo $resposta; ?>">

    <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
    <input type="submit" name="btResponder" value="Responder" class="btn"/><br><br>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<?php 

// Importando o rodape la do arquivo footer
require_once '../config/footer.inc.html' 

?>
```

Nos testes aqui deu certo!

Tinha TAG html depois de tag div! Removi também!

Espero ter ajudado! Qualquer coisa, só colocar nos comentários!

Comment: É apenas uma tabela o outro select existe mas é a mesma tabela foi apenas um erro na hora que colei o código aqui

Comment: Entendi! Então não precisa mesmo dos 2! Se quiser uma ajuda maior, teria que dar mais detalhes (Estrutura do Banco, código PHP e código HTML! Talvez o problema esteja na quantidade de dados da tabela e no Select mesmo!

Comment: Augusto Vasques Obrigado por tentar ajudar vou colocar o codigo completo, removi o laço for porque nao estava funcionando da maneira que eu gostaria, deixei so o rand , mas quando clico em responder ele faz o select de novo e ai repete palavras. Eu quero simplesmente passar posição por posição cada vez que eu clico em responder. (atualizei o codigo).

Comment: Atualizei a resposta!

Comment: @maxmodle se ajudou, favor avaliar a resposta :)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, ficou bem mais limpo o codigo com as variaveis boleanas, no entanto, ainda esta repetindo o ID na hora de escolha ai vem a mesma pergunta, to tentando encontrar uma forma de varrer o vetor um por um em um loop sem voltar e acho que o RAND() não vai poder eu tentei. ``` where id = "$id" ``` e em cada loop eu incrementava + 1 na variavel id pra pegar o proximo id só que ai ele varreu o vetor ate o final e não conseguir

Comment: Eu nunca usei as funções **mysqli**... do mysql antigo pulei direto para PDO! Pode estar ai o problema! Tenta adicionar na query WHERE id != $idPerguntaAnterior... você também pode armazenar em $_SESSION todas perguntas respondidas e filtrar por todas elas.... se esperar um pouco, posso estudar a mysqli para te ajudar mais...

Comment: Ah, você executando essa query no phpMyAdmin, ou qualquer outra interface, CADA VEZ VEM UMA PERGUNTA DIFERENTE?

Comment: Eu também estou estudando PDO, porque acho mais seguro, mas como isso é um sistema apenas pra meu uso eu fiz o msqli mesmo. Sim cada vez uma pergunta diferente tipo começando do id 1 ate ultimo da tabela

Comment: O que eu perguntei é se a QUERY está funcionando? O RAND... Testa fora do PHP... no HeidSQL ou phpMyAdmin....

Comment: Ta funcionando sim, eu testei no phpMyAdmin ele seleciona 1 pergunta "limite 1'' eu tenho que pensar em uma maneira de nao usar o RAND e seleciona 1 id por vez em um loop

Comment: Fiz uma nova resposta para a sua mudança de planos! Continuo achando que não está lidando bem com as funções *mysqli*! Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Duda Gervásio consegui, mas acho que é uma ganbiarra mas deu certo kkkk, eu nao conseguir fazer o loop pra incrementar na variável pq toda vez que clicava no botão ele reinicia a variável ai dentro do if do botão eu fiz um uptade e um incremento. Para isso eu criei uma tabela com um campo e ai eu faço o incremento dentro do banco e coloco na variável e pego ela e coloco no select da pergunta e pego o próximo id. Eu sei que essa não é a maneira correta mas deu certo valew Duda Gervásio